# foreach loop: the value of $key in if() give it to else

Tags: php

i got a foreach loop and in the part:

```
if(is_array($template)){
        $naam = $key;
        echo $naam;
```

**$key = name1, name2, etc**

```
}else{
        $this->templateHtml .= '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_'.$naam.$key .'" name="jezus" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" value="'.$template.'">';
```

**and in else $key = 1,2 ,3 etc**

what i want is to combine the values of the keys like this:

Name1_1 name2_1

name1_2 name2_2

Name1_3 name2_3

**$name.$key but I cant get the value from the if to the else**

```
public function recursiveTemplate($templates){

    foreach($templates as $key => $template){

        if(is_array($template)){
            $naam = $key;
            echo $naam;
            $this->templateHtml .= '<div class="input-group tempHolder"><span style="width: 155px;" class="input-group-addon" id='.$key.'>'.$key.'</span>';
            $this->recursiveTemplate($template);
            $this->templateHtml .= '
               <button type="button" class="btn2 btn-info"  id="addTemplate"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
               <button type="button" class="btn2 btn-danger"  id="deleteTemplate" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></span></div>';
        }else{
            $this->templateHtml .= '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_'.$naam.$key .'" name="jezus" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" value="'.$template.'">';
        }


    }

}
```

}

Comment: Where do you set the $naam property for the `else` part? And can you show an example what the wrong output is?

Comment: i tried to get  the value from if accesable for else but it didnt work current out put =
id_00
id_11

`foreach($templates as $key => $template){

           $naam = $key;

        if(is_array($template)){

               $naam = $key;`

Comment: Just add the outputs, the error or whatever you get to your post, which do not fit your expectations

Comment: My expectation is that I want to know how to make  the $key value  of **if(is_array)** accessible in the  **else()**

Comment: There is no difference in `$key` in `if` or `else`. The basic array your are iterating through has inconsistent key values. Just like `array(['name1'] => array(...), [1] => 'whatever', ['name2'] => array(...)`. That seems to be the problem for my point of view. Just use `print_r($templates);' to get the content of the array.

Comment: I am trying to create an unique id: if i got   **name.1 , name.2.** later if there is a new array i want to give it its name with it **name2.1 so it** stays unique

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have to use a variable that holds the name of the previous iteration. Just like this (I removed the HTML for tracking reasons):

```
$previous_name = "name1";

foreach($templates as $key => $template){

    if(is_array($template)){
        $previous_name = $key;        
        // if key is 'name1', $previous_name is set to $key
    }else{
        $previous_name = $previous_name . "_" . $key; 
        // if key is '1' and $previous_name is 'name1', the new content of $previous_name is 'name1_1'
    }
}
```